# Parse text file as list of variables?

Tags: text-parsing, jscript.net

I have a text file (currently in CSV format) as follows:

```
RACE,"race_human"
GENDER,"male"
AGE,30
ALIGNMENT,"align_lawful_good"
DEITY,"Old Faith"
```

However, I want to interpret the text file as if it were a list of variables. I.e.:

```
var RACE:string = "race_human";
```

Is there an easy way to do this, for instance reformatting the text file in the native language used by the program code?

Comment: you don't need to put categories like ".NET" in the title - that's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split each line on the comma then place each item into a dictionary (provided the keys are unique). Use [Dictionary.TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) if there's a chance that a key does not exist.

```
string[] input = File.ReadAllLines(CSV-File-Here);
var dict = input.Select(s => s.Split(','))
                .ToDictionary(s => s[0], s => s[1]);

// show alignment
string alignment = dict["ALIGNMENT"];
Console.WriteLine(alignment);

// show all values
foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, dict[key]);
}
```

EDIT: you might be interested in [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) to work with CSV files.

Comment: Cool. I am trying to use this (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) library at CodeProject, and am waiting to see if I get a response.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax for a JScript .NET dictionary object. I have "private var myDictionary: Dictionary<string><string>;", but the compiler complains that it's missing a semicolon and that the Dictionary object is not declared.

Comment: @posfan12 I'm not familiar with JScript.NET, you'll have to look around for examples. Also, is this current question for C# or JScript.NET? If it's the latter you might want to update your question to specify and add an appropriate tag for it.

Comment: It's for JScript .NET. Updated.

Comment: Also, I know JScript does have a native dictionary-like object format, but I'm not sure if there are disadvantages to using it instead of the .NET-specific construct. I.e., what if someone wants to extend my script using another .NET language? Will ask a separate question I guess.